# If $F(x)=\int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$, then is $F(0)$ implicitly defined as: $\lim_{x \to 0^+ }(\lim_{ε \to 0^+}\int^x_{ε}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})$?

Tags: calculus, terminology, improper-integrals

I am working through an exercise that will require me to have a workable understanding of improper integrals. I would like to make sure the following concepts are correct:

Suppose I have the function $F(x)=\int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$. Firstly, because $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cdot}}$ is a function that is not defined at $t=0$, we implicitly understand that $F(x)$ is actually shorthand for $\displaystyle \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\int^x_{\varepsilon}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$. From what I know, this amounts to a definitional *convention*. Next, suppose I am interested in the value $F(0)$ (assuming it exists...i.e. assuming $F$ is definable at $0$).

What is not clear to me is whether or not this, too, is shorthand for something...or just altogether invalid syntax. Would it be appropriate to think that $F(0)$ is just shorthand for $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+} \left(\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int^x_{\varepsilon}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)$? Is this convention? Or something I would have to explicitly define for my own purposes?

I bring this case up because $F(0)$ appears to approach $0$ when I use graphing software. Comparatively, in the case of $G(x)=\int_0^x\frac{1}{x}$, the graph does not even appear, which I suppose means that $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\varepsilon^+}^x \frac{1}{x}$ does not exist...but does $G(0)=\lim x \to 0^+ \left(\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\varepsilon}^x\frac{1}{x}\right)$ exist? How are such double limits calculated?

Comment: What you have written is in fact $\lim_{x\to 0+}F(x)$ rather than $F(0)$, and they may differ in general. I’d say that $F(0)=0$ just because it is an integral over an interval of zero length.

Comment: @Ilya thanks for your comment. My confusion stems from an exercise in a book. Specifically, I am given the statement: "$F / \log$ is unbounded on $[1,\infty)$". The author's choice to include the bracket on $1$ strikes me as peculiar. This makes it seem like the function $F / \log$ is necessarily defined at $x=1$...i.e. $F(1) / \log(1)$ is a finite value...but it is not clear to me what $F(1) / \log(1)$ is shorthand for. Do we implicitly interpret this as $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{F(x)}{\log(x)}$?

Comment: (1) $F(0)$ can not be naturally defined by plugging in $x=0$ in its formula directly. Basically it can be defined by any value, but it can be *continuously extended to $x=0$* by setting $F(0)=0$. This is not bather: for instance, $h: \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}\to\mathbb{R}$, where $h(x)=\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ for $x>0$ can not be extended continuously to $x=0$. (2) As for your added comment, $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{F(x)}{\log(x)}$ should be $+\infty$ since $\lim_{x \to 1^+} F(x)> 0$ (and exists) while  $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \log (x)=0$, $\log(x)>0$ when $x>1$.